# Inherit include directories from used library in CMake

Tags: cmake

**If I have a library with public header files which are used by another library's public header files how can I expose the former library's public header directory to a third application which depends only from the latter library *without explicitly adding the former library's header files' path to the application's target_include_directories section*?**

I know this is a bit confusing, here is a simple example:

I have two shared libraries and one application in the same cmake project:

- `library_foo` has a directory which contains its public header files
- `library_bar` has also a directory with its public header files. One of these public header files (`lib_bar/bar.h`) contains an `#include <lib_foo/foo.h>` entry, i.e. the public header file has a reference to a public header file defined in `library_foo`.
- `library_bar` implementation depends on `library_foo`.
- `app` depends **directly** only on the `library_bar`.
- `app`'s `main.cpp` contains an `#include <lib_bar/bar.h>`.

So, app depends **indirectly** from `library_foo` and its header files as well.

I would like to write three CMakeLists.txt files for these three parts of my application. In the CMakeLists.txt of `app` I would like to specify dependency only to `library_bar`, i.e. the library and header dependecies from `libarary_foo` which are specified in `library_bar` CMakeLists.txt must be transferred to `app`. How can I do this? I would like to use `target_*` solution.

Answer (score 4):

Command [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_include_directories.html) is used exactly for the purpose of inheritance:

```cmake
add_library(library_foo SHARED ...)
# Include directories are made an interface of 'foo'.
target_include_directories(library_foo PUBLIC <dir-with-lib_foo/foo.h>)


add_library(library_bar SHARED ...)
target_include_directories(library_bar PUBLIC <dir-with-lib_bar/bar.h>)
# Linking with 'foo' propagates include directories
# and makes these directories an interface of 'bar' too.
target_link_libraries(library_bar library_foo)


add_executable(app ...)
# Application will use include directories both from 'bar' and 'foo'.
target_link_libraries(app library_bar)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I also tried but somehow app could not see foo header files. I will double check it and send response here.

Comment: what about if you need to also inherit the directories from an interface library brought in by target_link_libraries?

Comment: Command `target_include_directories` is applicable for INTERFACE library too, if you ask about that.