# Creating c++ library using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

Dear cmake / c++ experts,

I created a small library for display and input on the console. Now I would like to use it in another project. Unfortunately, even after quite some time spent in the cmake documents, I cannot get it to work.

The library is here: https://github.com/HEIGVD-PRG1-F-2022/prg1f-io and uses the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(prg1f-io VERSION 0.1 DESCRIPTION "Input and display methods for PRG1-F")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

add_library(prg1f-io STATIC src/display.cpp)
set_target_properties(prg1f-io PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
set_target_properties(prg1f-io PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER include/display.h)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS prg1f-io
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})
```

And I created a small test here: https://github.com/HEIGVD-PRG1-F-2022/prg1f-test with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(prg1f_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(prg1f-io
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/HEIGVD-PRG1-F-2022/prg1f-io.git
        GIT_TAG main
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(prg1f-io)

add_executable(prg1f-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prg1f-test PRIVATE prg1f-io)
```

While the `CMakeLists.txt` in the test does download the library and compiles it, I cannot get access to the header files in the test. I tried different includes, but none of the following work:

```cpp
#include <prg1f-io/include/display.h>
#include <prg1f-io/display.h>
#include <prg1f-io>
#include <display.h>
```

I'm sure it's a little line somewhere in one of the `CMakeLists.txt`, but I cannot find it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you need something like `target_include_directories(prg1f-test PRIVATE ${prg1f-io_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: Thanks - that works! But it feels suboptimal - meaning I really don't understand how this cmake works. I was hoping that with the `PUBLIC_HEADER include/display.h` line I could then use something like `#include <prg1f-io>` in my `main.cpp`...

Comment: I'm not a CMake wizard, but maybe the library is indeed installed in the `include` directory, but nothing tells to your `prg1f-test` script to use `include` directory. Perhaps `include_directories(SYSTEM ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR})` in the `prg1f-test` script would force it for all targets

Comment: Unfortunately `include_directories` doesn't work - unlike your other solution, I cannot find how to `#include` the headers with this.

Comment: Your `CMakeLists.txt` for the library doesn't define include directories at all. A library's include directory with public headers is normally specified with `target_include_directories(<lib-target> PUBLIC <dir>)`. See e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262364/inherit-include-directories-from-used-library-in-cmake). Note, that PUBLIC_HEADER doesn't define include directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - great! This is exactly what I was looking for! Now I can directly `#include` my header files, without more lines in the `CMakeLists.txt`. What if I would like to have `#include <prg1f-io/display.h>` as include? Do I need to put my headers in such a directory, or is there a parameter to prepend `prg1f-io` to the include files?

Comment: A path passed to `#include` should be the "**real**" one. So you need to actually have `prg1f-io` directory to contain `display.h` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev, I can now rest in peace:

The `CMakeLists.txt` of the library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(prg1f-io VERSION 0.1 DESCRIPTION "Input and display methods for PRG1-F")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")

add_library(prg1f-io STATIC src/display.cpp)
set_target_properties(prg1f-io PROPERTIES VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
target_include_directories(prg1f-io PUBLIC include)
```

And the `CMakeLists.txt` of the binary using the library:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(prg1f_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(prg1f-io
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/HEIGVD-PRG1-F-2022/prg1f-io.git
        GIT_TAG main
        )
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(prg1f-io)

add_executable(prg1f-test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(prg1f-test PRIVATE prg1f-io)
```

Now I can include the headers using:

```cpp
#include <display.h>
```

All I'm missing now is how to `#include<prg1f-io/display.h>` without having to add a `prg1f-io/include/prg1f-io/display.h` directory.